# Single-line if-else statement expecting keyword_do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, syntax-error

I've been using single-line if-else statements for a long time, and just recently I've repeatedly kept getting this error:

```
registrations_controller.rb:88: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

This is the syntax I'm using in my current example, and I've double, triple, and quadruple-checked that the syntax is right:

```
resource.errors.any? ? render :new : do_something_else!
```

I've checked all around, and can't seem to find any changes, or similar issues.  Oddly, when I run

```
foo = [1,2,3]
foo.any? ? 'bar' : 'baz'
```

in my terminal, I get no errors.  I'm quite sure I've replicated what I'm trying to do in all relevant respects here, but can't seem to find a hint as to why this is happening.  I figured maybe there's a problem with `render`, but I don't think this is the case, as I got a similar error when trying to use `render 'new'` with a string instead of a symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `render` parameter into parenthesis.

```
resource.errors.any? ? render(:new) : do_something_else!
```

Otherwise, the parser will have some trouble to understand where the paramether begins.

Comment: Thanks! I probably should have made this connection :)